# A DNS that has been eliminated is still resulting in X.509 Certificate Subject CN Does Not Match the Entity Name

Tags: certificate-authority, vulnerability, x.509, vulnerability-scanners

I ran a Nexpose scan on a DNS that no longer resolves and a vulnerability was found : X.509 Certificate Subject CN Does Not Match the Entity Name

I don't know why it's still producing a vulnerability when the DNS should not even resolve.

How should I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to the community. This might be weird that such a sophisticated scanner might be doing just a silly mistake, but then again this might just be the case. If you manually checked it out, it shouldn't be a problem imho.

Comment: Have you verified that the DNS name no longer resolves on the scanning machine (check with `host`, `dig`, or `nslookup`)?  It could be cached somewhere, for example.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the X.509 certificate that was scanned is no longer valid because the domain name it was issued for no longer resolves. This can happen if the domain name has expired or if the website has been taken down. In either case, there is nothing to fix because the certificate is no longer in use.

If you are still seeing a vulnerability for this certificate in your scan results, you may need to update your scan engine to the latest version to ensure that it properly recognizes expired certificates. You can also try running a new scan to see if the vulnerability is still present.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to fix this is to remove the invalid X.509 certificate from the server or remove the DNS record from the DNS server. If the X.509 certificate is not removed, then the vulnerability will continue to appear in the scan results. It's also important to ensure that any new X.509 certificates are properly configured with the correct entity name.